# -whatever suffix

Tags: suffixes

Is there a Latin suffix meaning “-whatever”? E.g.:

Wikipedia, Wikisource, … Wikiwhatever.
*Vicipaedia, Vicifons, … Vici…(?).*

(But I'm not even sure that *-whatever* itself is a correct English suffix.)

Answer (score 5):

Quidquid, perhaps? See examples at Wiktionary under [quisquis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quisquis#Latin).

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is indeed a good option.

Comment: Right, this is basically a general info I already have from public sources, which does not include a suffix usage, like in the example.